# How to override ajax base url?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm developing two projects under one solution API and Web application.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and ports for each project are different when debugging, e.g. `localhost:32335` and `localhost:21890`, so now each time I need to use api I need to set localhost with that port.

I come up with solution to set default port to for example 1337, and in host file set `example.com` to `localhost:1337`, so now I just need to use `example.com/api/someaction`.

What I want to do is set base url in ajax so I don't have to retype example.com in my code, so basically I just need to type `/api/someaction` and ajax call will now to use `example.com` by default, not localhost:33181.

Comment: Just make a function to return the call. `function srvc(name){ return 'example.com/api/'+name; }`, then call it in the url like, `srvc('someaction')`..

Comment: @Ohgodwhy that seems a good workaround, but I would prefer altering `$.ajax()` function rather then poly-filling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start to work with your `iis`. create a different application with different domain name and edit your hosts file to use that address. don't use with the cassini. for each application  , create an application in the iis. add a binding , and create the different domain names in the hosts file.

Comment: This is a good solution. Mostly for production but I managed to use this on development too.

Answer (score -2):

Use jquery ajaxSetup:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  url: 'ping.php'
});
```

Comment: This will not work, as if he supplies `/api/someaction'`, the url will change in that ajax call to `/api/someaction`, because of the way `$.extend()` works to implement the settings into the ajax object. -1

Comment: Good point that I missed. Leaving this here as a good to know